Ray Cluster setup with "proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp connection refused"
Where are the possible places to configure K8S using a proxy as it repeats "proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1082: connect: connection refused" during setting up Ray Cluster?
Follow instruction Ray CLuster quickstart:
helm repo add kuberay https://ray-project.github.io/kuberay-helm/
helm repo update

# Install both CRDs and KubeRay operator v1.1.1.
helm install kuberay-operator kuberay/kuberay-operator --version 1.1.1

# Confirm that the operator is running in the namespace `default`.
kubectl get pods
# NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
# kuberay-operator-7fbdbf8c89-pt8bk   1/1     Running   0          27s 

in the step2. I get aErrImagePull status pod, and the real output:
(base) ➜  ~ helm install kuberay-operator kuberay/kuberay-operator --version 1.0.0                                                                                                                     [36/197]
NAME: kuberay-operator                                                                                                                                                                                         
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Jul 26 08:56:30 2024                                                                                                                                                                        
NAMESPACE: default                                                                                                                                                                                             
STATUS: deployed                                                                                                                                                                                               
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None        
(base) ➜  ~ kubectl get pods                                                                           
NAME                                READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
kuberay-operator-5d64d88fdb-shrkv   0/1     ErrImagePull   0          10s
(base) ➜  ~ kubectl describe pod kuberay-operator-5d64d88fdb-shrkv 
Name:             kuberay-operator-5d64d88fdb-shrkv 
Namespace:        default              
Priority:         0                
Service Account:  kuberay-operator                                                                     
Node:             kind-control-plane/172.23.0.2                                                        
Start Time:       Fri, 26 Jul 2024 08:56:31 +0800
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=kuberay-operator    
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=kuberay-operator     
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=kuberay-operator                                                                                                                                                      
                  pod-template-hash=5d64d88fdb         
.....
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  22s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kuberay-operator-5d64d88fdb-shrkv to kind-control-plane
  Normal   BackOff    21s               kubelet            Back-off pulling image "kuberay/operator:v1.0.0"
  Warning  Failed     21s               kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    6s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet            Pulling image "kuberay/operator:v1.0.0"
  Warning  Failed     6s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "kuberay/operator:v1.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/kuberay/operator:v1.0.0"
: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/kuberay/operator:v1.0.0": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/kuberay/operator/manifests/v1.0.0": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1082: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Failed     6s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull

The puzzle question is the message: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1082: connect: connection refused
I tried following ways but did not find any proxy configuration:
(base) ➜  ~  echo $HTTP_PROXY

(base) ➜  ~  echo $HTTPS_PROXY

(base) ➜  ~ cat /etc/environment                 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
(base) ➜  ~ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
    "registry-mirrors": [
        "https://5wxalzzb.mirror.aliyuncs.com",    
        "https://hub-mirror.c.163.com",
        "https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn",
        "https://docker.m.daocloud.io"
    ],
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "args": [],
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime"
        }
    }
}

To mitigate the pod issue, I started local port 1082, which is a HTTP proxy without  AuthZ & AuthN, and then re-install the kuberay/operator again, but the same error event message for proxy.

The error indicates that k8s cluster is attempting to use a proxy  server on your local machine at port 1082 to pull the image but it is unable to connect. It might be a configuration issue with the proxy.
You might not have a proxy server configured or running on your machine at port 1082.If you have a proxy server, its configurations might be wrong

@SaiChandiniRouthu Do you have idea where is possible places that confogures these 1082 port as a proxy?

@ Xu Shijie Have you gone through my solution & the answer helps to resolve your issue, if not let me know, I am happy to assist you further. –

It might be that the proxy got configured wrongly or there is no existing proxy server running on port 1082.

Do you have an idea where possible places that configure these 1082
ports as a proxy?


Did you look up your environment’s Proxy settings including HTTP PROXY, HTTPS PROXY and NO_PROXY environment variables.Other files like curl, wget or docker configuration can as well be examined for possible declaration of a proxy.
Let's find out if there are firewalls or network security policies redirecting traffic to port 1082.
Consider the Kubernetes configuration to find out whether it has anything on proxies. Check also kube proxy,configuration like env vars.
For example, if you are using Docker as a container runtime, ensure their configurations do not contain any abnormal network configurations and  proxy settings.
There may be some applications or tools having particular ports for internal communication. So what processes or services are running on port 1082

NOTE:
Temporarily turn off all proxies in your environment to see if this is what causes the problem.
Look for any error messages related to the network connectivity or proxy issues in the k8s logs.
If you are unable to resolve the proxy issue, try pulling the image from a different registry to rule out registry specific problems.
